# Missing Supabase modules after pulling from github

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, next.js

I'm creating a next app for work so I've been working on it on my home and work computers. Last night I was working on the project on my home computer that already had the Supabase package installed. I pulled my changes to my work computer. Supabase requests were working as expected. I committed and pushed my changes from my work computer and pulled them to my home computer when I got home. I started up the dev server in vscode and now I'm getting an error telling me the Supabase package doesn't exist. What's going on??

```
{
  "name": "nortech_retail",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.33.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your description, there could be a possibility as stated. You need to check your `package.json` file for updated dependencies.

Also, it is likely that node_modules/ path in your repository source is added to [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and is hence not tracked by Git, due to which your modules in work and personal home computer are not synced up (which is expected).
If you have added and pushed your changes from home computer and pulled them into your work computer as per your case, run `npm install` to install the new dependency in your system. Then proceed with running your application with either `npm start` or `npm run build`.